# pause all videos on page while current one is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have multiple html5 video elements on page
when play one of them I need to pause all others
here is my try:

```
$('.player').on('play', function(){
    console.log('playing'); // this works
    $('.player').not($(this)).pause();
});
```

and getting console error:

```
$(...).not(...).pause is not a function
```

any help?

Comment: `.pause()` is a method of the DOM `<video>` element. `.not()` returns a jQuery _collection_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pause()` is a DOM function, not a jQuery function. Try:

```js
$('.player').not($(this)).trigger('pause');
```